# circular progress bar progressing like pie chart

Tags: android, progress-bar

I have a progress bar whose progressdrawable 'drawable/circle_progress.xml' is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
       <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="0"
            android:toDegrees="360"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%" >

            <shape android:shape="oval" >
                <gradient
                    android:centerColor="@color/color_center"
                    android:centerY="0.50"
                    android:endColor="@color/color_end"
                    android:startColor="@color/color_start"
                    android:type="sweep" /> 
            </shape>

        </rotate>

    </item>

</layer-list>
```

My progress bar in xml is as:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBarCircle"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circle_progress"
    android:max="100" />
```

Here is the image of progress bar with progress 90%. when I increase the progress , It is rotated by amount of the progress.

[image: sample]
<sub>(source: [tiemenschut.com](http://www.tiemenschut.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/radar.png))</sub>

I just want , circle should be filled only by amount of progress like a pie chart, not all the circle.

Comment: then you need a custom Drawable: a class extending Drawable class

Comment: https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel

Comment: @pskink There is a class which extends drawable but don't know how to use it.
(https://gist.github.com/dcow/9493477)

Read my comment also there,

Comment: use yourProgressBar.setProgressDrawable(Drawable)

Comment: I tried but it is not working, at progress 0, circle is blank, but when I try to increment the progress by 10, it fills all the circle.
    circleProgressBar.incrementProgressBy(10);

Comment: @Hemant so debug draw method

Answer (score 2):

For those who wonder how to implement [this Drawable class](https://gist.github.com/dcow/9493477), I found the way. In my case I had to use a Pie Progress Drawable to show the progress of a countdown timer, updating the drawable every second. To do that I created an instance of the PieProgressDrawable class and set it to an ImageView:

```
PieProgressDrawable pieProgressDrawable = new PieProgressDrawable();
ImageView timeProgress = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.time_progress);
timeProgress.setImageDrawable(pieProgressDrawable);
```

In order to update the progress every second, I call setLevel() on the PieProgressDrawable instance and then invalidate() on the ImageView that hosts this PieProgressDrawable instance. Like this:

```
pieProgressDrawable.setLevel(progress);
timeProgress.invalidate();
```

In case someone needs some guidance I wrote a tutorial about it [here](https://irpdevelop.wordpress.com/2016/10/05/how-to-implement-pie-progress-view-in-android/).